Laravel - Image resize = Unable to decode image from file
I'm trying to resize an existing image file, but I'm receiving the error:

Unable to decode image from file (./public/sample.jpg).directory/public_html/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Gd/Decoder.php:81

Curiously, this error only happens:

In the production server
After converting a base64 string to image

Any other image (downloaded from internet) the resize works fine.
Function to upload a base64 string:
public function uploadBase64(string $base64): self 
{
    $file = str_replace('data:image/jpg;base64, ', '', $base64);
    $file = base64_decode($file);
    
    $filename = 'sample.jpg';
    
    Storage::disk('local')->put($filename, $file);

    return $this;
}

Function to resize an existing file:
public function resizeImage(string $filepath): string 
{     
    $manager = new ImageManager(['driver' => 'gd']);        
    $image = $manager->make($filepath);
    $image->resize(120, null, function ($constraint) 
    {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });
    $image->save($filepath);

    return $filepath;
}

This tells me that I'm not properly saving the base64 string (?), yet I can properly see the image.
Again: this works on my local PC,but not on my production server. However, in the production server, I can resize any other images, so it's not a GD library problem.
I've tried to save the image as png but no luck. What am I missing?

Why don't you inspect the value of $base64 and/or the contents of the file? That's basic debugging...

@Olivier I did. Like I said, the image is created perfectly, it's just the resize that doesn't work. I also tested this website https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image: the image is well converted, but when I try to resize it, it throws that error.

Could it be something related to the fact that it is an image being extracted from citizen card?

You should provide a link to your sample.jpg.

@Olivier wish I could, but it's my personal citizen card photo . Well, it's not a big deal, I just won't resize it.

If you are able to resize other images on production server, that means there is a bug in converting base64 to image.
    $file = str_replace('data:image/jpg;base64, ', '', $base64);

whats the use of the space after base64, ?

The space after base64 was just a space I added manually through JS. I just removed it, tested and the problem remains.
